# Show that there exist a constant c>0

Tags: calculus

Show that there exist a constant $c>0$ such that for all $x \in [1,\infty)$
$$  \sum_{n>=x}^{\infty} 1/n^2 < c/x. $$

Comment: i have used that 1/x^2 less than 1/x but cant get anything please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that for $x\ge 1$

$$\sum_{n>=x}^{\infty} 1/n^2 <\int _x^{\infty} \frac {1}{t^2}dt= \frac{1}{x} <2/x$$

Thus $c=2$ does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

If $x$ is an integer bigger than $1$, you can bound the sum by

$$\int_{x-1}^\infty  \frac{1}{ y^2 } \; d y.$$

If $x=1$, you have to tweak it a bit.  Then if $x$ is not an integer, you have a different little tweak.

Comment: if x is not an integer then

Comment: ....then draw a picture.  The integral is an area ans so is the sum.